# Why Directly Accesing property is not recommended in OOPs PHP?

Tags: php, oop

If I have a class "person" with a property $name and its getter(get_name()) and setter(set_name()) methods, then after instantiating the objects and setting the property i.e.

```
$paddy = new person();

$paddy->set_name("Padyster Dave");

echo "Paddy's full name: ".$paddy->name; //WHY THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED...
```

In the above code `$paddy->name;`WHY THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED

> **EDIT**

Above code is a sample code without assigning any accessifiers.. Its just to understand the $paddy->name concept

Comment: One buzz word in context of this: Information hiding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding And what you ask for  applies to OOP in general not just PHP.

Comment: I have used syntax of php and tagged the question to PHP section thats why added the keyword PHP, I am aware of this fact that its general for many..Thanksss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you might someday get rid of the `$name` member, replacing it with (e.g.) `$first_name`, `$last_name` and a `fullname()` method (not that that's a [good idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name)). Of course, with [`__get` and `__set`](https://www.php.net/__get), it doesn't matter so much.

More generally, setting a property might not be so simple as storing a value. Giving direct access to member fields can result in other functions causing an object to be in an inconsistent state. Imagine you store an array that needs to remain sorted; if the array were public, something else could assign an unsorted array to the field.

Answer (score 9):

The thing that's weird is that you have a setter, but are leaving the property `public`. (Assuming there's no `__get` magic going on.)

You usually want to use getters/setters to get more control over what can be assigned to a property and what can't. Or, you may want to execute code when the property is accessed or changed. In either case, you should force the use of the getters/setters by making the property `private` or `protected`, otherwise it's pretty pointless. It's about preventing yourself or others that will use the class from shooting their own foot.

If the setter in your example only sets the value without doing anything else, it's superfluous. If it does do something else that is required whenever the value is set, you have a flaw in your class design since it's possible to change the value without using the setter.

---

```
class Foo {
    public $bar = 0;  // is only allowed to contain numeric values
    public function setBar($val) {
        if (is_numeric($val)) {
            $this->bar = $val;
        }
    }
}

$obj = new Foo();
$obj->bar = 'some value'; // set a string, which is not allowed
```

If you'd make `$bar` `protected`, that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: "If it does do something else that is required whenever the value is set, you have a flaw in your class design since it's possible to change the value without using the setter." Can U elaborate this? plss

Comment: @Parth If you do `protected $bar = 0;`, `$obj->bar` is not allowed and will throw a warning. Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 3):

Exposing public fields would be a bad habit.From a [good artical](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-7oohabits/index.html?ca=drs-tp4408) about OO principle in PHP

**If anything changes with the object, any code that uses it needs to change as well. For instance, if the person's given, family, and other names were to be encapsulated in a PersonName object, you would need to modify all your code to accommodate the change.**

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I'm doing 'bad' things too as I use this sort of code all the time.

But what if $this->name (or as I would do $this->nameFormatted) is constructed like:

```
protected var $name;
$this->name = $this->getSalutation() . ' ' . $this->nameFirst . ' ' . $this->nameLast;
```

or something along those lines.

You're using $this->name out in the public context, but it's still constructed in the class and if it's protected it won't be overwritten.

Or am I missing the point and the 'bad' thing is actually set-ting the name in the public scope?